How do I fix the "holes" when importing complex SVG Paths into Grease Pencil?
I have text converted into an SVG path in Inkscape. When I import it into grease pencil the "holes" in some of the letters (o, a, p etc.) are all filled in. The curves are there, they have just taken on the color of the text. I could fix it with the bucket fill tool however the accuracy of following the curves is poor leading to awful looking text. Importing the text as a stroke only has the same issue, filling the text with the bucket fill tool looks awful.
I'm a beginner so I'm not familiar with all of the options. It seems to me that I should be able to apply a maetrial to the inner "hole" curves and have it match the boundary. Is there a way to do this with masking (which I don't understand yet)?



“the accuracy of following the curves is poor leading to awful looking text” Not sure what you’re referring to, though I’m not particularly familiar with grease pencil. Can you post a screenshot of the trouble?

@TheLabCat see the differences in shape for the before and after? The bucket fill isn't following the curves.

Changing color of holes
Grease Pencil doesn't support multiple strokes in the same path (stroke). That's why curves in the same path are converted in separate paths in GP. That's why you can select this parts(strokes), create a new material and assign them to a second material:

To assign selected strokes to a material, select them (as you do it in meshes) and press "Assign"

Materials are stored per stroke, so it is not necessary to select the whole stroke.

Creating real holes with masks
If you want holes to be transparent, you can do the following.
Move inner strokes into new layer, press M -> New Layer

I named it "mask"

Add created layer to mask list of the first layer, Enable masks checkbox and press plus icon:

Invert mask by pressing this icon:

Select the mask layer and set layer opacity to 0:

Done:


A suggestion on top of this: Compositing may be used to chroma key out the filled in areas to transparency if needed.

Drag-and-dropping an SVG file imports it as a Grease Pencil object. Alternatively, you can use:
File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
This method allows you to create a curve from the SVG, which you can then modify further, such as extruding or editing the geometry.
